# spring integration using udp Message mapping exception

Tags: udp, spring-integration

I'm running spring integration with udp inbound and outbound. I'm getting the following error, how can i solve this ?

```
13:37:12.346 ERROR [udpIn-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter][org.springframework.integration.ip.udp.UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter] Failed to map packet to message 
org.springframework.integration.mapping.MessageMappingException: Incorrect length; expected 1700885373, received 17
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.udp.DatagramPacketMessageMapper.toMessage(DatagramPacketMessageMapper.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.udp.UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter$1.run(UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter.java:146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your configuration but it appears you have set `check-length="true"`. This has to be the same on both sides (assuming you are sending from a Spring Integration app).

If you are receiving data from some other application; this attribute must be set to false (default).